# Having an issue with stopping a loop in Stata

Tags: stata

So, I have a bunch of variables in my data set which are binary and contain information on whether an individual was married or not. So, for example, `marr79`, is whether a person was married in 1979 or not.

I'm trying to find how many years a person was married (the first time) from the child's birth. So, if the child was born in 1980, and the person was married in 1980, it would add to `child_marr`, and it would do the same for the following 18 years of their life. I want it to stop, though, if it encounters a 0. So if there are 1's for 1980, 1981, and 1982, and a 0 for 1983, I want it to stop at 1983, even if there is a 1 in 1984.

My code below (and it is one of many iterations I've tried) either has it run through all the years without stopping, or never run at all, leaving values of all 0.

Any help is appreciated.

```
gen child_marr=0;
forvalues y=79(1)99 {;
gen temp_yr=1900+`y';   
if (ch_yob<=temp_yr & marr`y'==1 & temp_yr<(ch_yob+18))==1 {;
    replace child_marr = child_marr + 1;
    };
else if (marr`y'==0 & ch_yob<=temp_yr) {;
    continue, break;
    };
drop temp_yr;
};
```

Comment: It's not clear from you question what your data looks like. Could you post  a minimal, complete and verifiable example, along with desired output? You can use `dataex` from SSC.

Comment: {Warning: Opinion follows.} What on earth are all those semicolons doing in your Stata code? `#delimit ;` is useful in allowing the occasional very long command with line breaks, but why would you actively seek to clutter your code with extraneous characters when (a) it is not required and (b) it is very much against common coding practice in the language?

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- Your condition `if (test1 & test2 & test3) == 1` does not need the `== 1` portion -- Stata infers that `if (condition)` means `if condition == 1` (caveat: for cases where the logical test is `{0,1}`).
- There is no need to generate a temporary variable, since you can compare the value of a variable to a local macro directly.
- To the issue at hand, your loop is comparing observation-level criteria (*e.g.*, the value of the variable `temp_yr` to the value of the variable `ch_yob`). This can seem correct, but is often problematic -- see [Stata FAQ: if command versus if qualifier](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/if-command-versus-if-qualifier/).

A first pass at a solution would be to recode your `forvalues` loop to use the *`if` qualifier* rather than the *`if` command*:

```
gen child_marr = 0
forvalues y = 79/99 {
    local yr = 1900 + `y'   
    replace child_marr = child_marr + 1 if (ch_yob <= `yr') & (marr`y' == 1) & (`yr' < (ch_yob + 18))
}
```

But as mentioned, a concrete solution would be easier with a reproducible example.

Comment: Brendan, thanks for your assistance. The issue I'm having is not with the loop. The original loop is shaped the way you have it, but I'm creating another loop where I want the loop to stop if marr`y'==0

Comment: Further help would benefit from Dimitriy's advice of posting "a minimal, complete and verifiable example, along with desired output[.] You can use `dataex` from SSC."